# VBA Read XML file

Tags: excel, vba

Sample XML file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config urldb="works" version="10.0.0">
    <devices>
        <entry name="localhost.localdomain">
            <vsys>
                <entry name="vsys1">
                    <service-group>
                        <entry name="LAN_WAN_Internet">
                            <members>
                                <member>service-http-6660</member>
                            </members>
                        </entry>
                        <entry name="DMZ_WAN_Internet">
                            <members>
                                <member>service-http-80888</member>
                                <member>service-https-443</member>
                            </members>
                        </entry>
                        <entry name="LAN_DMZ">
                            <members>
                                <member>service-http</member>
                                <member>service-https</member>
                            </members>
                        </entry>
                    </service-group>
                </entry>
            </vsys>
        </entry>
    </devices>
</config>
```

With the following Code I can read entry name="LAN_WAN_Internet",entry name="DMZ_WAN_Internet> and entry name="LAN_DMZ" the output is this

```
LAN_WAN_Internet
DMZ_WAN_Internet
LAN_DMZ
```

Now I want to read /members/member from every entry, the output must like this
I have tested differnet things but no luck

Can someone please help me

Many Thanks

```
LAN_WAN_Internet service-http-6660
DMZ_WAN_Internet service-http-80888 service-https-443
LAN_DMZ service-http service-https


Sub ServiceGroup()
'On Error Resume Next

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Aufgabenplanung\Plotter\pafw01.xml")
Set Root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
num_nodes = Root.SelectSingleNode("devices/entry/vsys/entry/service-group").ChildNodes.Length
For i = 0 To (num_nodes - 1)
    Set current_node = Root.SelectSingleNode("devices/entry/vsys/entry/service-group").ChildNodes.Item(i)
    
    Debug.Print current_node.SelectSingleNode("@name").Text
  
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have XML files with more than one `service-group` you must iterate over that groups like it is done in the following code for `entry` and `member`.

Look here for the used methods:
[XML DOM Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757828(v=vs.85))

```
Sub ServiceGroup()

Dim nodeAllEntry As Object
Dim nodeOneEntry As Object
Dim nodeAllMember As Object
Dim nodeOneMember As Object

  With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    .async = False
    .Load ("C:\Aufgabenplanung\Plotter\pafw01.xml")
    
    Set nodeAllEntry = .getElementsByTagName("service-group")(0).getElementsByTagName("entry")
    
    For Each nodeOneEntry In nodeAllEntry
      Debug.Print nodeOneEntry.getAttribute("name")
      Set nodeAllMember = nodeOneEntry.getElementsByTagName("member")
      
      For Each nodeOneMember In nodeAllMember
        Debug.Print nodeOneMember.Text
      Next nodeOneMember
    Next nodeOneEntry
  End With
End Sub
```